# SearchKit + FormBuilder to display PCPs on Contact Record

Tags: searchkit, formbuilder, personal-campaign-pages, pcp

Goal:  Create a tab on contact records with a table of PCPs created by that contact.

Using SearchKit, I created a search:

- SearchFor: Personal Contribution Pages
- With: (required) Personal Campaign Page Contact

Using FormBuilder, I created a form:

- Checked: Add to contact summary page (as tab)
- Filters: I've tried 'Personal Campaign Page Contact' and 'Contact ID' from URL (cid)

I can't quite get it to return *only* the PCPs for a given contact record. Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I figured this out.

Instead of searching for PCPs with (required) PCP Contact, I need to do the inverse.

Search for Contacts with (required) PCPs.  That did the trick.

Incorrect:
[image: Incorrect:]

Correct:
[image: Correct:]